# VirtualBox Error : Kernel Driver not installed(rc=-1908)

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, debugging

I am currently using `Ubuntu 18.04` and VirtualBox GUI `Version 5.2.18` and I faced the following bug:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or
>   there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall
>   virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing
>
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
>
> as root.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
>   support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.

I don't know how to fix it and it is quite annoying because I am unable to start any VM.

**Edit:** I already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

and

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
```

The output is `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted`

But none of them works works.

Comment: Could you please at least tell me why you downvoted my question and/or how can I improve it?

Comment: @GAD3R thanks for your comment, you can find the output below: `insmod /lib/modules/4.18.0-16-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted
`

Comment: You have to run `modprobe` with `sudo`.

Comment: None of the commands you posted in your question would have reinstalled VirtualBox, as the error you received suggests that you do.  You should try `apt-get install virtualbox` and see if that helps with your issues.  Since VirtualBox utilizes a kernel module, you would need to make sure that module gets rebuilt every time your installed kernel changes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I updated my question, using `modprobe` with `sudo` didn't solved my problem
@GracefulRestart you can find the output below  `virtualbox is already the newest version (5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.3).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your system has UEFI firmware and Secure Boot is enabled, that might explain why you aren't "permitted" to load (unsigned) kernel modules.

Ubuntu is supposed to have an automated the signing process for third-party modules, but it is possible that the process hasn't worked as expected. For example, if you've updated your system's UEFI firmware ("BIOS update") since installing Ubuntu, the update may have caused a full reset of the system NVRAM. In that case, this command should start the re-enrollment process:

```
sudo update-secureboot-policy --enroll-key
```

If the auto-generated key is already enrolled, or in a few other possible cases, this command will simply print out a message about the state of Secure Boot key on your system, so it should be safe to try it anyway, and the message might be informative.

But if the key needs to be re-enrolled, the command will ask you to set a password. Then you'll need to reboot the system once, and immediately after rebooting, the component responsible for re-enrolling the key will request you to enter that password again. This procedure is designed to ensure that a Secure Boot key cannot be enrolled by without the user knowing what is going on. Once the key is successfully enrolled, that password will never be needed again, so there will be no need to store it for long term.

But if that does not solve the problem, something else might be wrong.

To get more information, you should look at the tail end of the kernel message buffer (`dmesg` command output) after attempting to load the module. In other words, please do this:

```
sudo modprobe vboxdrv
sudo dmesg | tail -30
```

The output should include a bit more verbose description on why the module loading is failing. If the Secure Boot key was not the problem, then please add the results of the second command to your original question.

Comment: I simply disabled secure boot in the BIOS setup. I guess that works too.

Comment: @Nicolay77 Your comment was the solution to my issue.

Comment: on WSL2 i get `EFI variables are not supported on this system`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Found this when I googled for solution.

Apparently `sudo apt install virtualbox` fixed the problem on my case.

Comment: Welcome, you have said it doesn't solve the problem here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/562852/suddenly-cant-start-vm-guest-in-virtualbox-5-2-34

Comment: @GAD3R, only for VM in saved session